# Ssh tunnel hanging infinitely when trying to connect to a Phpmyadmin MySQL database through Python

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I have a web app running on AWS Ubuntu and I am unable to connect to a database via ssh tunneling. I am able to access the db via MySQL workbench's SSH tunneling option but access via SSH tunneling on Python fails to work. Kindly suggest ways to solve it or of accessing a Phpmyadmin MySQL database other than via SSH tunneling.

```
from os.path import expanduser

pkeyfilepath = '/html/fbads/phpmyadmin-ec2.pem'
home = expanduser('~')
print(pkeyfilepath)
print("hello")
print(home)
mypkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(home + pkeyfilepath)
print(mypkey)


server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('ec2-52-91-169-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com', 22),
    ssh_username="ec2-user",
    ssh_pkey="~/html/fbads/phpmyadmin-ec2.pem",
    remote_bind_address=('phpmyadmin.cpsisadn02rn.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com', 3306)
    )
server.start()
print(server)

local_port = str(server.local_bind_port)
engine = create_engine('mysql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format("root", "passwd", "127.0.0.1", local_port, "passwd"))

dataDF = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM test;", engine)  #testing teh connection

#server.stop()  #use this command to stop the connection
```

Comment: To start with is the remote_bind_address correct? and  "select * from test;" can also done via the mysql cli option other than the phpmyadmin

Comment: Hi Ali, thanks for the suggestion. One of the requirements is to use phpmyadmin, and so mysql cli is not an option. Update: the ssh tunneling works on a flask app running locally but hangs only when running on Ubuntu server. I set the remote bind address as 'remote_bind_address=(db_host, 3306)'